# Is there a way to select multiple rows but only return columns that are distinct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So for instance, say I have this data in a table:

```
Code    Price   Pay.     Adj.   Post date   Enc Date    Department
1160F   0.01    NULL    -0.01   20191009    20190930    Plastic Surgery
1160F   0.01    NULL    0.00    20191009    20190930    Plastic Surgery
1160F   0.01    0.00    NULL    20191009    20190930    Plastic Surgery
```

But I want to display the information like this:

```
Code    Price   Pay.     Adj.   Post date   Enc Date    Department
1160F   0.01    NULL    -0.01   20191009    20190930    Plastic Surgery
                         0.00   20191009    
                0.00            20191009
```

So I essentially want to be able to pull all unique first rows, but only display the post date and either adj or payment of the following rows based off a unique id. Hopefully this makes sense!

Here is the full snippit of sql I'm using.

```
select TOP 1000 pe.enc_id, pe.enc_nbr, pm.description [Rendering], pm2.description [Supervising], c.cpt4_code_id,  c.amt, 
sum(td.paid_amt)  as [Payment], sum(td.adj_amt) as [Adjustment], 
c.closing_date as [Date of Payment], convert(varchar, pe.enc_timestamp, 112) , ml.mstr_list_item_desc as [Department], ml2.mstr_list_item_desc as [Financial Class]
from person p join patient_encounter pe on p.person_id = pe.person_id
join provider_mstr pm2 on pe.supervisor_provider_id = pm2.provider_id
join patient pa on p.person_id = pa.person_id
join charges c on pe.enc_id = c.source_id and pa.practice_id = c.practice_id
join location_mstr lm on pe.location_id = lm.location_id
join provider_mstr pm on pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
join transactions t on c.source_id = t.source_id 
join trans_detail td on t.trans_id = td.trans_id and c.charge_id = td.charge_id
left join mstr_lists ml on pm.provider_subgrouping2_id = ml.mstr_list_item_id
join encounter_payer ep on pe.enc_id = ep.enc_id
join payer_mstr pay on ep.payer_id = pay.payer_id
left join mstr_lists ml2 on pay.financial_class = ml2.mstr_list_item_id
join service_item_mstr sim on c.cpt4_code_id = sim.cpt4_code_id and c.closing_date between sim.eff_date and sim.exp_date and c.service_item_lib_id = sim.service_item_lib_id
where convert(varchar, pe.enc_timestamp, 112)  between '20181001' and '20190930'
group by med_rec_nbr, pe.enc_nbr, p.first_name, p.last_name, date_of_birth, enc_timestamp, location_name, pm.description, pm2.description, c.cpt4_code_id, amt, td.paid_amt, td.adj_amt, pe.enc_id, c.closing_date,ml.mstr_list_item_desc, p.zip, sim.rvu1,
sim.description,ml2.mstr_list_item_desc, t.post_date
order by pe.enc_timestamp desc
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Read [mcve] first!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016